# Ajax Not Working in page in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following Script tags in may header.php file.
         
    ">

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'); ?>"></script>

<!-- Select Plugin Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js'); ?>"></script>

<!-- Slimscroll Plugin Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js'); ?>"></script>

<!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/plugins/node-waves/waves.js'); ?>"></script>

<!-- Jquery CountTo Plugin Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/plugins/jquery-countto/jquery.countTo.js'); ?>"></script>
<!-- Custom Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/js/admin.js'); ?>"></script>

<!-- Demo Js -->
<script src="<?php echo  base_url('resource/temp/js/demo.js'); ?>"></script>
```

and these files are again loaded in the footer file as well along with some other .js files. With all the documents, I cannot call ajax function in one of my pages to populate an option list.

I want to populate a select option list when I click on the other option select field. But its not working. Please help. I tried changing latest jquery.min.js files as well. The min.js file version used in the template is 1.12.4.

Below is my Page where ajax call is used.

```
<div class="form-group form-float">
                             <div class="form-line">
                            <label>Union</label>
                                <select class="form-control union" name="gunion" id="union"  required >
                                <option value="">-- Please Select--</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($union as $row)
                                    {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row->u_name;?>"><?php echo $row->u_name;?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                               </select>
                                 <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error('tonque'); ?></span>     
                                 </div>

                                  <div class="form-line">
                            <label>Sakha</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="gshaka" id="sakha" required>
                                <option value="">---Please Select--</option>

                               </select>
                                 <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error('tonque'); ?></span>     
                                 </div>
```

and the Script:

```
         <script type="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#union').on('change',function(){
    var unionID = $(this).val(); 
    console.log(unionID);
    if(unionID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getsakha/'+unionID,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                $('#sakha').html(html);
                    }
        }); 
        }else{
        $('#sakha').html('<option value="">Select Union first</option>');
 }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you see any error message in developer console of browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `javascript` from script tag of type attribute

`<script type="javascript">`

add `type="text/javascript"` in your script tag

`<script type="text/javascript">`

OR either remove `type` attribute

`<script>`

This happens because there are not type attribute of `javascript` but there is `text/javascript`. If you are not writing `type` attribute then it will consider as a `javascript`

I hope this may help you.

Comment: ;; Thanks a lot...I was too absent minded to see that mistake.

Comment: Vote the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

remove repeated script files and load all script files in the footer.
or you can use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/